# Initialize jquery action at bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

What I want to accomplish is basically create 'a kind' of infinite scroll on my single.php (wordpress) file. I don't want to use the infinite scroll plugin because if applied to single.php it either won't work either it'll create glitches regarding URL. Instead, I wanna use jquery to detect if user has reached the bottom of the page and then somehow initialize an action to "click" on the 'next article' link. I'm still at the beginning when it comes to coding so currently I have managed to only create the bottom check code and I got stuck. Any suggestion on how to finish this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            alert("bottom!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it working at all? Wordpress uses a no-conflict DOM ready handler, and it's own way of including scripts with dependencies, start by reading the codex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fake a `click` with the click method http://api.jquery.com/click/

```
$( "#target" ).click();
```

(implying your "load more" link has an attibute `id="target"`

Answer (score 0):

What you have is, indeed, correct.

I suggest you check your JavaScript console for errors, and make sure it is the bottom of the *page* you're scrolling to, and not a content div.  Also, try reducing the number of pixels from the bottom, so it initializes *before* the bottom of the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height() - 100) {
            alert("bottom!");
        }
    });
});
```

(note the `- 100`)

Also, if you're using WordPress, jQuery should be referenced with `jQuery()` and not `$()`, unless you're passing it as a variable in the `document.ready` call, which you don't appear to be doing.